# Rake db:migrate error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm getting this error when running rake db:migrate

rake aborted!
Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment

Any ideas about it?

Comment: How about doing what the message says?

Comment: @madth3: because the activerecord-mysql-adapter gem isn't a "thing". It's the `mysql` gem that is missing.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add the `mysql2` gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

And also use the `mysql2` adapter in your `config/database.yml`:

```
adapter: mysql2
```

Comment: Ok. I just created the project again and it works... I guess some configuration file was wrong... Tks!